# Using Pandas to filter Excel table

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have imported an Excel table using Pandas. The table contains four columns representing Nodes, X, Y and Z data.  I used the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
SolidFixity = pd.read_excel('GeomData.xlsx', sheetname = 'SurfaceFixitySolid')
```

What I would like to do next is filter this dataframe using the filter table to select the Node of interest. I used this command:

```
SolidFixity.filter(like = '797', axis = 'Nodes')
```

This did not work and threw the following error:

> ValueError: No axis named Nodes for object type

I know there is an axis named Nodes because the following command:

```
In[17]SolidFixity.axes
```

Outputs the following:

```
Out[17]: 
[RangeIndex(start=0, stop=809, step=1),
 Index(['Nodes', 'X', 'Y ', 'Z'], dtype='object')]
```

Nodes is right there, shimmering like the sun.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `SolidFixity[SolidFixity.Node.eq('797')]`?

Comment: While the answer below is getting updated, edited and fleshed out in general: what you are doing wrong is that you are using a label filter to scan for contents. 'Nodes' is a label of axis=1, not an axis by itself.

Comment: That returns `SolidFixity.filter(like = '797', axis = 1)
Out[29]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]

[809 rows x 0 columns]` which is an empty dataframe. I know node 797 is in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with mask by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) or compare with `797` for exact match:

```
SolidFixity = pd.DataFrame({'Nodes':['797','sds','797 dsd','800','s','79785'],
                            'X':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (SolidFixity)
     Nodes  X
0      797  5
1      sds  3
2  797 dsd  6
3      800  9
4        s  2
5    79785  4

a = SolidFixity[SolidFixity.Nodes.str.contains('797')]
print (a)
     Nodes  X
0      797  5
2  797 dsd  6
5    79785  4

b = SolidFixity[SolidFixity.Nodes == '797']
print (b)
  Nodes  X
0   797  5

b = SolidFixity.query("Nodes =='797'")
print (b)
 Nodes  X
0   797  5
```

[`filter`](http://panda.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function have possible axis only values:

> axis : int or string axis name
>
> The axis to filter on. By default this is the info axis, `index` for Series, `columns` for DataFrame

and return all columns by parameters `like`, `regex` and `items`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C797':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   '797':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   797  A  B  C797  E  F
0    1  a  4     7  5  a
1    3  b  5     8  3  a
2    5  c  4     9  6  a
3    7  d  5     4  9  b
4    1  e  5     2  2  b
5    0  f  4     3  4  b

a = df.filter(like = '797', axis = 1)
#same as
#a = df.filter(like = '797', axis = 'columns')
print (a)
   797  C797
0    1     7
1    3     8
2    5     9
3    7     4
4    1     2
5    0     3
```

---

```
c = df.filter(items = ['797'], axis = 1)
#same as
#c = df.filter(items = ['797'], axis = 'columns')
print (c)
   797
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4    1
5    0
```

Comment: can I add boolean operators to that query statement? Say i wanted to select by X and Y value...

Comment: Sure `b = SolidFixity.query("Nodes =='797' & X == 1 & Y == 5")`

Comment: Nice... I opted for that since it has solved my problem. Accepting answer now

Comment: Thank you, nice weekend!